# How to have Hex automatically selected in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

Whenever I click the color pikcer in Illustrator the H is automatically selected, I usually work with HEX colors is it possible to have the HEX # automatically selected upon opening the color picker?

[image]

Comment: I would say no. But there is a possibility to use a different workflow (see here for some [discussion a while back](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33684790#33684790))

Comment: Using the **Color Panel** is far more efficient in Illustrator than the using the Color Picker.

Answer (score 2):

If you access the colour picker by double clicking on the fill or stroke colour in the toolbar then the hex value is selected by default. The little radio button next to H (Hue) may well be highlighted (or a different radio button, depending on what you were doing last), but the TEXT in the HEX box will be highlighted as in the following screenshot... 
[image]
So, if you're just wanting to tap in a HEX value for a new colour then you can double click the fill (or stroke) in the tool bar, type your value and hit enter. Done.

The Illustrator on the Mac in front of me is version 19.2.1 (2015.2.1 Release) so I can't vouch for any other or more recent versions, but I'm pretty sure that has always been the behaviour and hopefully this is still the case.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Mac - Illustrator 21.0.0. I double click on the fill that is on the left toolbar and the Hue is still highlighted. Even if I have previously written in a HEX value. Am I clicking on the right fill icon?

Comment: Curious. I can't get it to work any other way than how I described it above. Photoshop CC 2015 does the same thing. It's possible that my information (like the version of CC on my work Mac) is out of date.

Comment: If my color mode in Photoshop is RGB, then the HEX box will be selected, but I am not able to do the same in Illustrator with RGB color mode.

Comment: Thank you, but as the others have pointed out this saldi does not work in Illustrator 21.0.0.